# Missing tags, unexisting tags in search form within products, please help

Tags: tags

Could you check this link?

[Bathroom fittings | Slavine za kupatilo](http://noks.rs/?wpsc_product_category=slavine)

On the right side there is search form and for "Cena" (That is Price for artical, on Serbian) there are 3 tags. One of them is unexisting, "5310", and I am wonder how to remove it. Through dashboard option Post Tags I could find no even one tag even if I set in Screen Options to show 999 tags.

What am I supposed to do?

Thanks in advance, kind regards.

Ivan

Answer (score 1):

The dropdown will be probably created by the `get_tags()` function inside your template file, a shortcode or a widget.

Unfortunately, it's really hard to help without a code snippet here. Is the theme self scripted? Do you know WordPress and can edit the files? Who is the developer of the site? Maybe you can ask this question on a support forum of the developer?